# passing file as argument to docker run

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have a python3 command line script that uses argparse to read the arguments and give the results. It works fine when I run from terminal as:

```
my_cli --input input.csv --output output.csv --number 8
```

---

I dockerized it successfully and trying to run as:

```
docker run --mount type=bind,source=/tmp/path,target=/app my_cli_container --input input.csv --output output.csv --number 8
```

I get:
**FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:input.csv**

What I am doing wrong here ?
Why is the container not able to see the input file ?
Do I have to do something extra to read this input file and number, and then write output to a file ?

Thank you.

Comment: A Docker container runs in an isolated file system.  If your process's goal is to read and write host files, it will be much easier to run it outside Docker, possibly in a Python virtual environment if you need additional library dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

This will depend on what the location of `input.csv` is both inside and outside the container, and the working DIR in the container.

You are passing through `/tmp/path` to `/app` but is `input.csv` in the folder `/tmp/path` outside of the container
If not then the container wont be able to get to that file

If it is then is the working DIR inside the container `/app`? Otherwise you will need to pass in `--input /app/input.csv`

Also note that any files written by the container (out.csv) will be written as the user in the container (probably root), so may not be readable by your user